# A puzzle concerning Q objects and Foreign Keys

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-q

I've got a model like this:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    property1 = models.IntegerField()
    property2 = models.IntegerField()
    property3 = models.IntegerField()

class Subthing(models.Model):
    subproperty = models.IntegerField()
    thing = modelsForeignkey(Thing)
    main = models.BooleanField()
```

I've got a function that is passed a list of filters where each filter is of the form {'type':something, 'value':x}. This function needs to return a set of results ANDing all the filters together:

```
final_q = Q()
for filter in filters:
        q = None
        if filter['type'] =='thing-property1':
            q = Q(property1=filter['value'])
        elif filter['type'] =='thing-property2':
            q = Q(property2=filter['value'])
        elif filter['type'] =='thing-property2':
            q = Q(property3=filter['value'])
        if q:
            final_q = final_q & q
return Thing.objects.filter(final_q).distinct()
```

Each Subthing has a Boolean property 'main'. Every Thing has 1 and only 1 Subthing where main==True.

I now need to add filter that returns all the Things which have a Subthing where `main==True` and `subproperty==filter['value']`

Can I do this as part of the `Q` object I'm constructing? If not how else? The queryset I get before my new filter can be quite large so I would like a method that doesn't involve looping over the results.

Comment: there's a typo, should be models.ForeignKey()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit easier to understand if you explicitly give your Subthings a "related_name" in their relationship to the Thing

```
class Subthing(models.Model):
    ...
    thing = models.ForeignKey(Thing, related_name='subthings')
    ...
```

Now, you use [Django join syntax](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) to build your Q object:

```
Q(subthings__main=True) & Q(subthings__subproperty=filter['value'])
```

The reverse relationship has the default name 'subthing_set', but I find that it's easier to follow if you give it a better name like 'subthings'.

Comment: Doh! For some reason I was looking for a much more complicated solution than that! This seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Using (instead of `final_q=Q()` in the beginning)

```
final_q=Q(subthing_set__main=True)
sub_vals = map(lambda v: v['value'], filters)
if sub_vals:
    final_q = final_q & Q(subthing_set__subproperty__in=sub_vals)
```

should get you what you want, you can also adjust your loop to build the sub_vals list and apply it after the loop.

subthing_set is and automatically added related field added to the Thing to access related Subthings.

you can assign another related name, e.g.

```
thing=models.ForeignKey(Thing,related_name='subthings')
```